# Jquery ajax request doesn't work because of CORS error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors

i have a calendar and i would like to show when i click on a day what is in my php file. I did a ajax request but i have a 403 error and says  : "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

here is my code :

```
<div id="my-calendar"></div>
<div id="ladiv" style="display:none ;height:100px; width:100%; border:2px solid grey;"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
            language: "fr", 
            show_previous: false, 
            show_next: true,
            cell_border:true
        });

        $("body").on("click", "tr.calendar-dow td", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url:"******.org/custom/include/javascript/lib/ajax/test_ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (code_html) { 
                    $("#ladiv").html(code_html)
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error:function () {
                    console.log("failed");
                }
            });
        });
```

and here is my simple php file :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
$vari2='<p>variable 2</p>';
echo $vari2;
```

but i still have this error :

> GET http:///*********lib/ajax/test_ajax.php 403 (Forbidden)
>   Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://****/lib/ajax/test_ajax.php' from origin 'http://****' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Do you know how i can fix that pls ?

Comment: @DKyleo — No, not a duplicate of that. The OP has `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: `crossDomain:true,` is pointless here. It only makes any difference if you are making a **same-origin** request which gets **redirected** to a different origin.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the error message carefully:

> GET http:///*********lib/ajax/test_ajax.php **403 (Forbidden)** Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://****/lib/ajax/test_ajax.php' from origin 'http://****' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The server **didn't run the PHP** (so it didn't output the header your PHP code will output), it forbade access to it instead.

You need to figure out why that is the case. Maybe the file permissions on the server don't allow the HTTP server software to read the PHP file. Maybe you have to Authenticate (you *do* have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try to check the server permissions.  the server permissions are in the htacess i guess, right ?

Comment: No, on the file system.